# How can I have a traditional src/main/scala directory in a Play Application?

Tags: scala, playframework

I wish to move some of my normal SBT Scala code across to my Play Application. So my first thought was I'll just create a src directory and put it there, but it seems not working.

What is the right way to put normal Scala code into the Scala Play Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it should be done in the following way:

```
disablePlugins(PlayLayoutPlugin)
PlayKeys.playMonitoredFiles ++= (sourceDirectories in (Compile, TwirlKeys.compileTemplates)).value
```

Described here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Anatomy#Default-SBT-layout

Answer (score 7):

Adding

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "scala"
```

in your build.sbt should do the trick.